# Retreveing a file from internal storage and displaying it

Tags: android, file, textview, storage, internal

How do i read a text file from internal storage and display it in a textview?

So this is the situation, on a second activity i have two edittext saving the input data to two separate files. I want to retrieve those files and display the separate content in separate textviews.

```
public void refreshHandler(View view) 
 {
    TextView textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    String myData = "";
    try {
    File myInternalFile = (Names.txt);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myInternalFile);
     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(in));
     String strLine;
     while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
     myData = myData + strLine;
     }
     in.close();
     } 
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
     }
     textView7.setText(myData);
     textView8.setText(myData);

    }
```

Comment: what you have tried post your code..

Comment: use FileReader and pass that to your buffered reader, look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html. Also, use StringBuilder to append to then call toString() on the builder to get the String